# JBOSS, How can i add the dependancy javax.jmx?

Tags: jboss, jmx, javax

Please help: When i deploy a my.war jboss is throwing:

> > 9:12:16,777 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service
> >     jboss.module.service."deployment.my.war".main:
> >     org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> >     jboss.module.service."deployment.my.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to
> >     load module: deployment.my.war:main
> >             at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91)
> >             at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
> >             at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.jmx:main
> >             at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1093)
> >             at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1449)
> >             at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1477)
> >             at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
> >             at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68)
> >             ... 5 more
>
> 09:12:16,783 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deployment" => "my.war")]) - failure description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.my.war\".main" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.module.service.\"deployment.my.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed
>   to load module: deployment.my.war:main
>       Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.jmx:main"},
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.module.service.\"deployment.my.war\".main"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i just removed the dependancy from the deployment descriptor.
it was a mistake from me adding it there.
Thanks